# Streaming huge gzip file from s3 using boto3 python

Tags: python, python-2.7, boto, boto3, botocore

I have a 4GB gzip file on s3, I am trying to read the gzip file and write the decompressed contents to another file. How would I do this using boto3 python without loading the whole file into memory?

Comment: I am at the same issue. I am not able to understand which one solves the "without loading the whole file into memory" problem.